# 大风绝尘而去 in idiomatic English

Tags: translation, phrase

"大风绝尘而去" In a weather report document, such as http://news.163.com/14/0528/18/9TBR0KOI00014Q4P.html, does this phrase mean that the gale is going to 'stay away and leave' ? or 'A large storm will avoid the area'? What does 绝尘 mean in general? Thanks

Comment: While 大风 and 绝尘而去 are pretty normal Chinese phrases, 大风绝尘而去 simply isn't idiomatic Chinese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

绝尘

ABC：

move very fast

KEY：

1 run as if flying

2 be above mundane thoughts

A netizen on Baidu Zhidao defines 绝尘而去 as：脚不沾土,形容奔驰得飞快

Another explains it this way:
绝是消失不见
绝尘就是消失在扬起的尘土里
绝尘而去就是飞快的离去了，消失在马蹄扬起的尘烟里

I would translate 大风绝尘而去 as big winds (are going to/will) sweep through